# Retrieve attachments from email via IMAP?

Tags: php, imap

```
<?php
        $mailbox = "myServer";
        $user = "myUserName";
        $pass = "myPassWord";

        $connection = imap_open($mailbox, $user, $pass) or die ("Can't connect: " . imap_last_error());
        $list = imap_getmailboxes($connection, "myServer", "*");

        if(is_array($list)) {
            foreach($list as $key => $val) {
                echo "($key)";
                echo imap_utf7_decode($val->name) . ",";
                echo "'" . $val->delimiter . "',";
                echo $val->attributes . "<br />\n";
            }

        } else {
            echo "imap_getmailboxes failed: " . imap_last_error() . "\n";
        }            

        /* Search mailbox for unseen messages */
        $search = imap_search($connection, 'UNSEEN');

        $header = imap_headerinfo($connection, 1);
        $emailFrom =  $header->from[0]->mailbox . "@" . $header->from[0]->host;

        if($search) {
            echo $emailFrom;
        }


        /* Close the mailbox */
        imap_close($connection);
    ?>
```

This is my code... so far it connects via IMAP perfectly and gets the emails and that, how would I get it to retrieve the attachments of those e-mails? Any help would be appreciated! thank you

Answer (score 0):

There's plenty of these qustion on stackoverflow already. Have you tried to search?

- [Extracting PHP IMAP attachments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773169/extracting-php-imap-attachments)
- [PHP imap download attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12632446/php-imap-download-attachment)
- [Save Attachments Server with IMAP and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467188/save-attachments-server-with-imap-and-php)

Comment: I have, unfortunately these methods provide stupidly long ways of doing it. Doesn't matter, done it anyway.